# How can I avoid using a TSQL select distinct in this situation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, distinct

I am tuning a query that is running a select distinct on millions of records. I'm a bit inexperience with the execution plan, but my understanding of distinct, is we want to avoid using it because of the additional overhead required to weed out duplicate records.

Is there a way to rewrite the below example without using distinct?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#ORDERS', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ORDERS

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#CUSTOMERS', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CUSTOMERS

CREATE TABLE #ORDERS (OrderLineItemID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), OrderID INT, PRIMARY KEY (OrderLineItemID));

CREATE TABLE #CUSTOMERS (CustomerID INT, OrderLineItemID INT, PRIMARY KEY (OrderLineItemID));

INSERT INTO #ORDERS (OrderID)
VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (2), (2), (3), (3), (3), (3), (3), (3), (3), (5), (5), (5), (5), (5), (5);

INSERT INTO #CUSTOMERS (OrderLineItemID, CustomerID)
SELECT OrderLineItemID, CASE 
        WHEN OrderLineItemID <= 3
            THEN 15
        ELSE 20
        END
FROM #ORDERS
```

The query result needs to pull CustomerID and OrderID, but each order has a separate line item within. The below pulls all results.

```
SELECT C.CustomerID, O.OrderID
FROM #CUSTOMERS C
JOIN #ORDERS O ON C.OrderLineItemID = O.OrderLineItemID
```

Non-Distinct Result:

```
CustomerID  OrderID
15  1
15  1
15  1
20  2
20  2
20  2
20  2
20  3
20  3
20  3
20  3
20  3
20  3
20  3
20  5
20  5
20  5
20  5
20  5
20  5
```

But if we add distinct to the select, we get the desired results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.CustomerID, O.OrderID
FROM #CUSTOMERS C
JOIN #ORDERS O ON C.OrderLineItemID = O.OrderLineItemID
```

Distinct Result:

```
CustomerID  OrderID
15  1
20  2
20  3
20  5
```

Is there a better way of writing this to perform more efficiently?

Comment: In general, if a mature system offers a built-in way to do something, you're probably not going to write a more efficient workaround.

Comment: Your schema seems to be the primary problem. Generally speaking, schema problems will lead to cumbersome and inefficient tsql. Why do I say "problem"? I know of no real-life situation where an order is associated with different customers - in your case each item within the order is related to a customer. Addressing the schema issue might solve many problems.

Comment: This is just an example. The real data actually has nothing to do with orders. I threw this together to demonstrate how the non-distinct joined query will return duplicates vs the distinct.

Comment: And therefore your situation, as stated, is misleading making the comments and suggestions less useful. But the general implication stands - the need to use DISTINCT is often caused by a schema issue or a logically flawed query. And Oso is correct - you probably cannot outperform a built-in function. I will also point out that your resultset is not ordered and row order is usually important. DISTINCT will often cause the rows to appear ordered simply because of runtime factors - but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: The comments are still applicable, because the example is setup exactly the same way as the source I'm querying. I could have made the column headers more ambiguous, sorry if that caused confusion. Anyways, it sounds like there is no workaround in this situation without an overhaul of the schema. The developers who put this together have no intention of making enhancements. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use windowing function `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve the same result. Not sure, whether it will give better performance. When in doubt, better test it out.

```sql
SELECT CustomerID, OrderID
FROM
(
SELECT C.CustomerID, O.OrderID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C.CustomerID, O.OrderID ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNK
FROM #CUSTOMERS C
JOIN #ORDERS O ON C.OrderLineItemID = O.OrderLineItemID) as t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be an improvement. `DISTINCT` can use either a sorting strategy or a hashing strategy. This forces a sort strategy.